# Conditional sql query to fetch substring

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `"anx_m1`" . IT has the below 3 fields

```
OCCURTIME,OBJECTNAME,ID
```

the values are as shown below

22-JUL-15,Installmx_CHX sd:21 postcheck neutral,PNT_22715_13

22-JUL-15,Installmx_F sd:23 postcheck affected,PNT_22715_2

22-JUL-15,Installmx_TPONS sd:993 precheck invalid,PNT_22715_131

Now I need to move these values into a different table "amxm_stage" with below logic.

```
select OCCURTIME,ID,substr(OBJECTNAME,1,13) AS ONAME from anx_m1 where OBJECTNAME like 'Installmx_CHX sd:21%';

select OCCURTIME,ID,substr(OBJECTNAME,1,11) AS ONAME from anx_m1 where OBJECTNAME like 'Installmx_F sd:23%';

select OCCURTIME,ID,substr(OBJECTNAME,1,15) AS ONAME from anx_m1 where OBJECTNAME like 'Installmx_TPONS sd:993%';
```

I tried the above. But how can I use just a single sql statement to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try CASE Expression

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    select OCCURTIME,ID,
    case 
    when OBJECTNAME like 'Installmx_CHX sd:21%' then substr(OBJECTNAME,1,13) 
    when OBJECTNAME like 'Installmx_F sd:23%' then substr(OBJECTNAME,1,11) 
    when OBJECTNAME like 'Installmx_TPONS sd:993%' then substr(OBJECTNAME,1,15)
    end as ONAME
    from anx_m1 
) T where ONAME is not null
```

Comment: ONAME is getting "null" value with the above query

Comment: Not . It is not running .

Comment: It works fine. Just remove "AS ONAME" from "AS ONAME from anx_m1 "

Comment: How can we use http client and http post be integrated to internet using pentaho?.

I tried using http client specify server details, but it is not working.

 we search for some data over internet and fetch it? Please help.

How can I fetch "https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/9546_PDI%20Beginner's%20guide_SampleChapter.pdf" . If not, what other operation can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could `union all` your queries, but this is simpler solution:

```
select OCCURTIME, ID, substr(OBJECTNAME,1,instr(objectname, ' ')-1) AS ONAME 
  from anx_m1 
  where OBJECTNAME like 'Installmx_CHX sd:21%'
     or OBJECTNAME like 'Installmx_F sd:23%'
     or OBJECTNAME like 'Installmx_TPONS sd:993%';
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df189d/1)</sup>